# Excel QueryTable does not load webpage

Tags: vba, excel

I used a webpage to download information into a excel worksheet. Specifically, the old yahoo finance API

```
myurl = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=01&b=01&c=2016&d=01&e=01&f=2017&g=d&ignore=.csv"

'this is the old web address

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & myurl, _
Destination:=ws.Range("a1"))
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            .SaveData = True
```

It worked perfectly, until one month ago. The yahoo finance API changed, so the new one is:

```
myurl = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=1493218887&period2=1495810887&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=Uaszml8dA0M"

'this is the new web address
```

somehow when i replaced the new 'myurl', the programm gives an 1004 error message 
"unable to open (myurl) you cannot download the information you requested"

Comment: I suggest you use `excel-vba yahoo finance` as a search term using SO's search, then sort the results into "Newest" order.  You will find plenty of associated information.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Yahoo has canceled the ability to download historical stock prices, check the Yahoo Forum, Admin post by Nixon on 5-17/2017 02:59 PM. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym7aI.png)